# How can I practice Jean-Robert Argand idea of the rotation of a square root of -1

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-numbers

I am studying complex numbers and I really need an intuition on how they work.
I found the following video of Mathematician named Adrien Douady

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2kbM96Jr4nk

He explains complex numbers in a algebraic geometry way, as he mentions using his protractor and turning it by 180 degrees to represent multiplication by (-1). But then at 4:26 he mentiond a mathematician Robert Argand http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Robert_Argand, and that he had a great Idea. "He said to himself, since multiplying by -1 is a 180 degree rotation, the square root is 1/2 of 180 degree rotation. How is this? how can I practice this? from what philophy of mathematics does this come from?

Thank and forgive me if I sound to dumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For vectors on the plane, the mapping $v\mapsto c\cdot v$ is zooming the vector by scalar $c$, if $c\in\Bbb R$.

When we *compose* two such maps, $f:=v\mapsto c\cdot v$ and $g:=v\mapsto d\cdot v$, we have that $g\circ f=v\mapsto d\cdot c\cdot v$.

In particular, if $c=d$, we get $v\mapsto c^2\cdot v$.

The mapping  $s:v\mapsto -v$  can be indeed viewed as the rotation by $180^\circ$. Let us find its square root(s)!

Both rotations $r_{1,2}$ by $\pm90^\circ$ are such that $r_1\circ r_1=s=r_2\circ r_2$.

This can be set in a correspondence with the complex imaginary units $\pm i$.

---

This way, complex numbers can be identified with '*zooming-and-rotating*' transformations of the plane:

- The complex number $1$ corresponds to the identity, i.e. zoom by $1$ and rotate by $0^\circ$.
- $0$ corresponds to the degenerated zooming by $0$, i.e. the mapping $v\mapsto 0$
- A positive real number $c$ corresponds to the zooming by $c$ (i.e. $v\mapsto c\cdot v$) and no rotation (i.e. rotating by $0^\circ$)
- A negative real number $-c$ (with $c>0$) corresponds to the zooming by $c$ and rotating by $180^\circ$.
- The imaginary unit $i$ corresponds to rotation by $+90^\circ$ (and no zooming, i.e. zoom by $1$).

Addition of complex numbers corresponds to 'pointwise addition' of these transformation:
$$(f+g):=v\mapsto f(v)+g(v)$$
(There's an important point hidden here: try to prove that $f+g$ is again a 'zooming-and-rotating' transformation.)

Multiplication of complex numbers corresponds to *composition* of these transformation.

Comment: So complex numbers come about when c=d and we get c^2? those are vectors right? (I am trying to understand sentence 2,3 of your answer)

Comment: Errh... Start a clear page for your thoughts... I talked about $c^2$ because 'square root' (of a rotation) was mentioned.. I have updated my answer. say if anything is unclear.

Comment: So if I understand well, and linguistically speaking, one place we need complex numbers is because of the rotation and the zoom? Because we need to move back and forth a point that need's to be scalled negativly or positivly without loosing its information and there was a gap with negative roots? So mathematicomechanically it was not allowd since the invention of the i?

Comment: yes, something like that. We don't really *need* complex numbers. They just *exist*. The first place where complex numbers are mathematically needed, is the formula for the roots of cubic polynomials. If all the $3$ roots are real, then we have to move out to $\Bbb C$ for applying the formula (but imaginary parts will finally cancel each other).

Comment: REALLY thank you. I think I got a good working pattern in my mind on were we need this. Can you direct me to some good books were I can read more about complex numbers? thank you again